# Error when using withCredentials in a Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, ssh, jenkins-pipeline

In one of the stages of my Jenkins pipeline, I do

```
    stage('SSH into the Server') {
        steps {
            withCredentials([sshUserPrivateKey(
                credentialsId: '<ID>',
                keyFileVariable: 'KEY_FILE')]) {
                sh '''
                cat ${KEY_FILE} > ./key_key.key
                eval $(ssh-agent -s)
                chmod 600 ./key_key.key
                ssh-add ./key_key.key
                ssh-add -L
                ssh <username>@<server> docker ps
                '''
            }
        }
    }
```

Just to simply ssh into a server and check `docker ps`.

The `credentialId` is from the `Global Credentials` in my Jenkins server.

However, when running this,

I get

```
+ cat ****
++ ssh-agent -s
+ eval 'SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-.../agent.57271;' export 'SSH_AUTH_SOCK;' 'SSH_AGENT_PID=57272;' export 'SSH_AGENT_PID;' echo Agent pid '57272;'
++ SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-.../agent.57271
++ export SSH_AUTH_SOCK
++ SSH_AGENT_PID=57272
++ export SSH_AGENT_PID
++ echo Agent pid 57272
Agent pid 57272
+ chmod 600 ./key_key.key
+ ssh-add ./key_key.key
```

And just fails with no more messages.

Am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your intention, I think that's a very complicated way to do it.
I'd strongly recommend using SSH agent plugin.

https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/ssh-agent/

You can achieve it in one step.

```
  sshagent (credentials: ['<ID>']) {
    sh 'ssh <username>@<server> docker ps'
  }
```

Use the same UserPrivateKey's credentialsId from the Global Credentials that you mentioned above.

Comment: I used this way to run npm install and npm start, unfortunately the terminal will automatically closed right after it runs the npm install, so the npm install never be finished. Any other way to run a process through ssh?